# How do I fix invalid syntax error when importing postgis in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, postgis

I'm new to python and I am trying to transfer data in a PostgreSQL database with the postgis extension. My code is written in Python 2.7 and I am using the PyCharm IDE.

When I am trying to import the postgis module:

```
import postgis
```

I get an 'invalid syntax' error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/HDFtoPostgres/SendToPSQL.py", line 1,    in <module>
    import postgis
  File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/HDFtoPostgres/venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/postgis/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .geometry import Geometry
  File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/HDFtoPostgres/venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/postgis/geometry.py", line 14
    class Geometry(object, metaclass=Typed):
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To me it looks like the geometry.py is written in Python 3.x but is interpreted as Python 2.7 and thus crashes at this point. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You will inevitably get suggestions to update your code to Python 3 sooner rather than later. By the original timetable, Python 2 would be dead already, and it's clearly visible that experts and library maintainers are increasingly reluctant to support, let alone solve problems with, the moribund Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the `postgis` package shouldn't really install in Python 2 environments, since [its page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/postgis/) suggests it's only approved for Python 3.5 and 3.6.

There isn't really an easy way around this other than to migrate your code to Python 3 if `postgis` is an essential component. Alternatively you might try backporting `postgis` to Python 2.7, but that's an exercise of unknown complexity.